# How to remove first word if starts with 2020- from a text file

Tags: linux, logs, sort

I have a large log (text file) and want to sort it.
Most lines start with a timestamp and end with a ]
I don't the timestamp as part of the sort process so I thought I'd first delete all timestamps then sort the file.

Most entries in the log file look something like this:

```
2020-06-06T03:19:43:155Z DEBUG [user:dev009-abf][group:15789][host:abs12][someapp][yadda yadda yadda]
```

Comment: For a decent sample input, put at least 3 lines. And add **expected output**. One more point, better show us what you have searched/tried

Comment: I need to clarify as I wasn't so clear in my original question.  The below perl command works however it sorts each individual line and not taking into account that the end of each line (or section) is a ].  In other words each line actually contains multiple lines but ends with a ].  I need to sort the sections and each section ends with ]

Answer (score 1):

Easy, if you have perl installed:

`perl -pe 's/^\S+Z\s+//' <filename> | sort`

This strips the first "field" (as delimited by any space character), if that field ends in a Z.

You can remove the single character Z from the expression to always strip the first field.

edit: Or, if you really want to limit to 2020- only, just make it `'s/^2020-\S+\s+//'`

Comment: This works!  Can I also do this in a python or bash script?